# can we check if the same package (npm package) loaded twice on the sharepoint modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx-webparts

we are using private module (equivalent to dll) for logging the issue in SPFx to list. i am not sure if the private module is been downloaded multiple time or one time on the modern page.

we are using the same private module in different web part on the page. Please let me know how does module load at run time.

Comment: the question is not clear to me :) , what do you mean by module ? can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve and what is the exact issue that you are facing ?

Comment: Hi Gautam, thanks you for your comment. we build a solution (package) for logging the issues and warning to a list.  and we use npm link to share that solution(node moule shared) across the project. we are using the same logging module in many web parts on the SharePoint page. since we refer the same shared module , i am wondering if this loaded once or multiple time on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use developer tool to monitor loaded js file, for example:

[image]

If you just defined some 'common' module, I think it will be compile into the bundle, while if you referenced external js library, you could control whether compile into bundle or not. [Check official guideline.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries)

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your response. I did notice about bundle. and i am using webpack bundle analyser to check. however, that is really not proving if the module loaded once or multiple time.